# How to get WebView URL in W10 Mobile (UWP) (Xamarin forms)

Tags: url, webview, uwp, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an application for W10 Mobile (UWP) in Xamarin forms and I have implemented a WebView and I tried to get the URL of this but it is more complicated than I thought at first, I tried to get it through the source property, but not is possible, I would appreciate a help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an event handler to the navigation completed event.
With that you can check the URL
example:

```
WebView browser = new WebView();

browser.Navigated += OnNavigatedHandler;
public void OnNavigatedHandler (object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs args){

Console.WriteLine ("Navigated to: " + args.Url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble getting the URL of the browser in real time, the way you indicate I enter an infinite loop, I have a binding in my WebView on the SourceProperty in the view model called URL, when there is a change in the URL property I detect it thanks to PropertyChanged, the problem is that the event navigated only runs when updating the value of the URL property which causes the infinite loop to load the WebView infinitely. Is there any other way to get the URL?

**I have uploaded in Pastebin the classes of the test project I am using:**

**View:** pastebin.com/msyu9dJF

**ViewModel:** pastebin.com/LaCfC31c

**BaseViewModel:** pastebin.com/i6GCFbbe

Comment: You have to be more exact, what do you mean with real time? at which moments do you want to check the url etc

Comment: I want to get the URL every time there is a navigation in the WebView, the problem is that the event navigated only runs when updating the property SourceProperty What causes the WebView is updated constantly.

Comment: I found a bug with the Navigated event in Bugzilla, I haven't found a workaround. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41760

Comment: And is there an alternative to getting the URL?

Comment: Not that I can think of, I find it weird that you get an infinite loop, do you get it from the first one or?

Comment: It is normal to produce an infinite loop because the URL property has a binding with the Source property, the problem is what you say the event has a native bug. The only way I have found for the navigation event to run is to update the linked property, but this causes the infinite loop logically.